# Create a presentation table from List

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data in a "Data Table" as follows:

[image: Data Table]

I want to create a Presentation Table mapping ID to Code 1, and return Code 2 as the value as follows:

[image: Presentation Table]

I am struggling to find the right formula to return the Code 2 value based on ID and Code 1 values.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Are they always unique?  Will there ever be a time where the combination of ID and Code 1 are the same?

Comment: Hi Scott, The combination will always be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$9=$E2)*($B$2:$B$9=F$1),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then drag over and down.

Or you can use this formula that does not require the Ctr-Shift-Enter but is entered normally:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$9=$E2)*($B$2:$B$9=F$1),),0)),"")
```

[image]